# Using xfce by keyboard

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, mouse

I'm using Xfce as my default desktop. I was wondering if one can use it completely by keyboard without mouse? Such that some button combinations simulate mouse movements and some other simulates button presses. I have a handicap so I can work more accurate by keyboard than by mouse.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `xfce`, but I have configured `fvwm2` on my laptop to work mostly with the keyboard (switching between windows, resizing windows, etc.), in case it doesn't work with `xfce`. I'm sure the remaining functions that need a mouse could also be replaced somehow.

Answer (score 9):

Use xorg native mouse keys:

```
$ setxkbmap -option keypad:pointerkeys
```

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Num Lock</kbd>, then you can navigate mouse pointer with numpad.

[image]

More information at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_keys